# Force place image on table environment

Tags: tables, graphics

I have a compact summary sheet with 3 tables, two short tables and a long table. Something like this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \footnotesize
%Short table 1
            \begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
\end{tabular}
            \hfill
%Short table 2
            \begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
\end{tabular}
            \hfill 
%Long table 3
            \begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want to place an image under the two short tables, to the left of the long table, to have something like this:

[image: We want the picture to be in the blue space, where the tables are in gray.]

3 tables in gray, header and footer in pink and desired image position in blue.
I already tried using tikzpicture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [shift={(0.7 cm,0.7cm)}]  at (current page.south west){\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{pic.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And plugging all kinds of numbers for the shift, but it would always just skip that page (with the tables) altogether.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  Here I put all the images and tabulars inside a master tabular.  Note that I set the widths and heights of the images to match the space required for the tabulars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength\tempdima

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \footnotesize
% store tabulars in saveboxes
  \sbox0{\begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
    a & b & c
  \end{tabular}}%
  \sbox1{\begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
    d & e & f
  \end{tabular}}%
  \sbox2{\begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
    g & h & i\\
    j & k & l\\
    m & n & o\\
    p & q & r\\
    s & t & u\\
    v & w & x
  \end{tabular}}%
% compute excess needed space for long table
\ifdim\dp0>\dp1 \tempdima=\dp0
\else \tempdima=\dp1
\fi
\tempdima=\dimexpr \dp2-\tempdima\relax
% master tabular
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr \wd0+\wd1+\wd2+4\tabcolsep},height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
    \usebox0 & \usebox1 & \smash{\usebox2}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr \wd0+\wd1+2\tabcolsep},height=\tempdima]{example-image}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr \wd0+\wd1+\wd2+4\tabcolsep},height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]